# Flutter Web -- embedding HTML tag

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm building a Flutter web app and want to embed a full page Typeform survey via HTML code. I have the HTML snippet--how would I add this so that the page renders this HTML directly?

Comment: You can use WebViews or Iframe to do that, but, remember, there's no native support for scrolling events so far, so, any scrolling events over the WebView or Iframe won't be passed to flutter and the page containing other flutter widgets won't scroll. One of the worst drawback of Flutter Web.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your HTML code inside an IFrameElement in Flutter. IFrameElement will render inside flutter widget hierarchy and has the ability to run HTML code/pages.

More information here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/IFrameElement-class.html

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind providing an example of how I can do this? I just tried placing it in within a Scaffold and returning IFrameElement() from the build and I'm unable to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [easy_web_view](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view) plugin.

See:
https://medium.com/@anjana.pai.rathod/how-to-add-custom-html-code-to-flutter-web-app-bea2852ced5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).